# Addons installation failure

Tags: error, installation

I installed an addon of simply cloth pro, but when I come to mark it in the window of the addons, it says to me that there is an error.
Attached is a picture of what they write to me.[image]

Comment: We can only offer help with Blender's built-in addons and even then any errors should be reported by the built-in Help > Report a Bug menu.  For third-party addons, you'll have to report any errors to the addon author.